# Angular Service Multiple Constructors

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a regular angular service with @Injectable(). The constructor has dependecy injections for other services. I also want to instantiate a variable in the service through constructor. If I define multiple constructors for teh service like this, I can initialize but cant access the variable from the first constructor. For example:

Angular Service Code. Let's call it Service1

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {IndexedDBSvc} from '../../services/IndexedDBSvc'
import { LoaderService } from "../services/LoaderSvc";


@Injectable()
export class DllSvc {

  private dbVersion: number;

  constructor(version:any)
  constructor(private indexedDBObj?: IndexedDBSvc, private loadersvc?: LoaderService) {
     //Constructor implementation
     //Here I need to intialize **dbVersion** like this
     this.dbVersion = version; //But I cant access **version** inside this constrcutor
  }
}
```

Angular Component Code

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Service1 } from '../../../../../Services/Service1';

@Component({
  selector: 'rm-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})

export class component1 implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   constructor(private svc: Service1){
      this.svc = new Service1(5); //this is how I try to initialize the variable through constructor
   }
}
```

The question is how do Initialize a variable in the service through service constructor (with constructor overload or without constructor overload).

Comment: This is a [perfect case for an Event Service](https://dev.to/jwp/the-angular-event-service-ech)  Don't use but a single constructor and events for the rest.

Comment: Angular services are singletons, you shouldn't be using a constructor. Create a setter method to modify the behavior of your service.

Comment: @GarrettManley _Angular services are singletons_. Nope. Only if not provided through a providers array in a module or component type and providedInRoot == true.

Comment: I was unaware you could have multiple constructors. Why would you think version would be available in the second constructor when it's not provided in the arguments? It looks like you're trying to stack constructors. I don't think the second one would inherit from the first but I could be wrong.

Comment: It doesnt have to be multiple constructors. That is how I tried to solve it, but it didnt work. My main aim is to be able to intialize dbVersion variable inside the service, when I instatitae the servicein the component. How can I do that?